# Como mudar a cor da linha do edittext programaticamente

Tags: android, android-layout, edittext

Preciso alterar a cor da linha do EditText programaticamente, como faço?

Tentei definir um xml na pasta drawable, mas ele não muda a cor da linha mesmo assim...

Answer (score 2):

A partir da versão ***v22.1*** da ***appcompat-v7*** é possível definir um *style* e atribui-lo ao *EditText* através do atributo `android:theme`.

No arquivo `res/style.xml` declare um novo *style*:

```
<style name="MyEditTextTheme">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#00ff00</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/accent_material_light</item>
</style>
```

***Notas:***

- Altere as cores ao seu gosto.
- Com estas definições a linha é vermelha quando *"out focus"* e verde *"in focus"*
- Se o seu *theme* for *dark* utilize `@color/accent_material_dark`
- Para que funcione a sua *Activity* terá herdar de `AppCompatActivity`

Adicione o atributo `android:theme` à declaração do *EditText*:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    .....
    .....
    android:theme="@style/MyEditTextTheme"/>
```

<sub>Adaptado [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30150754/2556111)</sub>

Comment: Tentei definir isso em meu style, mas ele exibe "Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorControlActivated'." para os 3 itens

Comment: Veja a minha edição

Comment: Já testou após a edição que fiz? Ela responde à sua pergunta?

Comment: Ainda dá o mesmo erro, minha api é lvl 8 se não me engano, será incompatibilidade?

Comment: `minSdkVersion="8"` não tem problema, o problema pode estar é na `targetSdkVersion`. Você deve usar em `targetSdkVersion` sempre a ultima versão disponível, que neste momento é a 23. Eu testei com `minSdkVersion="8"` e `targetSdkVersion=23`

Comment: Testei agora com `minSdkVersion="8"` e `targetSdkVersion=8` e funciona. Julgo que os únicos requisitos são: v22.1 da appcompat-v7 e a Activity herdar de AppCompatActivity.

Comment: Resolvi o meu caso alterando o arquivo `colors.xml` na pasta `values`

Comment: @BrunoAgenor Sim, isso também serve. No entanto, além da cor da linha do edittext, também vai alterar a cor de outros componentes e isso pode não ser o desejado.

Comment: Realmente @ramaral, no meu caso eu queria alterar tudo mesmo

Comment: Por que Ramaral precisa ser a última versão disponível em targetSdkVersion?

Comment: @Aline, eu queria dizer `compileSdkVersion`. É aconselhável usar sempre a última versão do SDK para compilar. A razão é que a última versão, além de possíveis bugs terem sido corrigidos, acrescenta outras funcionalidades, normalmente em conjunto com a última versão da appcompat.

Comment: Hummm quando eu crie um projeto eu escolhi a API mínima 17...(   minSdkVersion 17) e o meu compileSdkVersion veio na mais recente versão do android...eu mudei o compileSdkVersion para a versão 23. Isso não tem problema para um aparelho que é mais antigo??? Deixando o compileSdkVersion  na versão mais atual do aparelho

Comment: @Aline, não. Use sempre a mais recente em `compileSdkVersion` e a correspondente appcompat. O que tem impacto nos aparelhos mais antigos é `minSdkVersion`. Veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/150859/2541) onde é dada uma pequena explicação sobre os diferentes `xxxSdkVersion`. Veja também este [post](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd).

Comment: Obrigada. Entendi!

Answer (score 0):

Não tem como mudar a cor da linha. É possível alterar o background do EditText e você pode pôr um `.PNG` transparente com uma linha colorida embaixo, como este por exemplo:

[image]

Para gerar estes `.PNGs` coloridos online você pode usar este site [Android Holo Generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/).

Porém, recomendo baixar a biblioteca [MaterialEditText](https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText) que implementa EditTexts com Material Design e possui o recurso de alterar a cor da linha programaticamente