# Quais as versões do SDK Android que, no mínimo, devo ter instaladas?

Tags: android, android-sdk

Quando baixei o Android Studio e abri o SDK Manager ele mostra alguns pacotes para serem baixados e instalados. Vi que tem diversas versões de Android.

As minhas dúvidas são:

- Quais deles são "extremamente" indispensáveis para que eu possa fazer build de App Android na minha máquina?
- Por exemplo: Quero rodar na versão android 5.1.1. Preciso realmente baixar os mais de 10GB do pacote 5.1.1 inteiro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Também tive essa dúvida quando comecei a programar para Android.

Geralmente uso uma lista pequena de pacotes (o mínimo necessário) porque eu não dependo de emulador para testar o código, testo direto no Smartphone.

Lista mínima:

Tools:

- Android SDK Tools
- Android SDK Platform-tools
- Android SDK Build-tools

Android N.N (API NN)

- SDK Platform

Extras

- Android Support Repository
- Google Repository

Substitua NN pelo nível de API que é seu alvo **android:targetSdkVersion** (22 é para Android 5.1).

Caso você programe no Windows talvez vá precisar do **Google USB Driver**.

Se você precisa de um emulador, não precisa baixar todas imagens, baixe apenas as que tem **Intel x86 Atom System image** ou **Intel x86 Atom_64 System image** (se seu computador for de 10 anos pra cá). Obs.: é bom ter no mínimo uns 8 GB de RAM.

Um caso em que o pacote **Android Support Repository** é necessário é quando seu **android:minSdkVersion** difere do **android:targetSdkVersion**.

Answer (score 6):

> Quais deles são "extremamente" indispensáveis para que eu possa fazer build de App Android na minha máquina.

As versões que tem de ter na sua máquina são:

- A versão mais recente. Deve compilar sempre a aplicação usando a versão mais recente da API. Assim poderá utilizar todos os recursos do SDK, incluindo os novos que não existem em versões anteriores.
  Deve indicá-la no *build.gradle* em `compileSdkVersion version`.
- As versões para as quais quiser criar emuladores. Se quiser testar a aplicação num emulador com Android 3, tem de fazer o *download* da API 11.

> Quero rodar na versão android 5.1.1. Preciso realmente baixar os mais de 10GB do pacote 5.1.1 inteiro?

- Não, desde que siga a regra de usar sempre a API mais recente para compilar a aplicação.
- Sim, se quiser criar um emulador com *Android* 5.1.1 para testar a aplicação.

Onde a sua aplicação pode rodar, depende do que foi informado no *build.gradle* em `defaultConfig`(equivalente á *tag* [`<uses-sdk>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) no *AndroidManifest.xml*).

Ela tem três atributos:

- `android:minSdkVersion="integer"`
- `android:targetSdkVersion="integer"`
- `android:maxSdkVersion="integer"`

Esses três atributos permitem à aplicação informar a sua compatibilidade com uma ou mais versões do Android.

O seu significado é o seguinte:

- `android:minSdkVersion="integer"` - Indica o nível mínimo da API requerido para a aplicação correr. O Android não deixará que a aplicação seja instalada em dispositivos com um nível da API inferior ao valor indicado por este atributo.
- `android:targetSdkVersion="integer"` - Indica o nível da API para o qual a aplicação foi feita.
  Informa o sistema que a aplicação foi testada para correr nesse nível e o sistema não deverá disponibilizar qualquer tipo de "comportamento de compatibilidade" para a executar em dispositivos com nível de API igual.
- `android:maxSdkVersion="integer"` - Indica o nível máximo da API em que a aplicação pode correr.
  O Android não permitirá que a aplicação seja instalada em dispositivos com um nível da API superior ao valor indicado neste atributo.

  **Atenção:** A declaração deste atributo não é recomendada, as novas versões da API são desenhadas para serem compativeis com as versões anteriores. Não há razão para intensionalmente bloquear a possibilidade da aplicação ser instalada em novas versões.

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem essa afirmação: **A versão mais recente. Deve compilar sempre a aplicação usando a versão mais recente da API. Deve indicá-la no build.gradle em compileSdkVersion version.** Existe alguma razão para isso? Ou melhor, se eu não utilizar a API mais recente não irá funcionar?

Comment: @Randrade Ao utilizar a versão mais recente irá poder utilizar todas os recursos dessa versão, recursos esses que poderão não existir em versões anteriores.

Comment: Entendi. É que ao ler aquela afirmação eu entendi outra coisa. Mas obrigado por esclarecer. :p