# Como mudar a cor da linha que fica em baixo do EditText via xml

Tags: android, android-layout, edittext

Como mudar a cor dessa linha que fica em baixo do EditText via xml?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/97683/2541

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Experimente fazer dessa forma:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Something or Other"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
```

Atenção, só funcionará com a API 21 ou superior.

Se tiver uma versão inferior, pode tentar desta forma:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText app:backgroundTint="@color/blue_gray_light" />
```

Comment: Certinho! Obrigado pela ajuda :)

Comment: De nada, sempre às ordens! Já agora, dê um UP na resposta se lhe foi útil :)